# How to retain SlideToggle in jquery using cookie or anything else?

Tags: jquery, cookies, slidetoggle

This function is called to hide my `div` initially:

```
function hideFunction() { 
   $(".user").hide();        
}
```

This is used to check cookie value:

```
function checkCookie() {
    if ($.cookie('panel') == 'open') {
        $('.user').slideDown(0);
    } else {
        $('.user').slideUp(0);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    hideFunction();
    checkCookie();

    // Toggle Panel and Set Cookie //
    $("#show_hide").click(function () {
        $(".user").slideToggle(function () {

            if ($(".user").is(':hidden')) {
                $.cookie('panel', 'closed');
            } else {
                $.cookie('panel', 'open');
            }
        });
    });
```

**Note**: `user` is a class for my `div`  and `show_hide` is class of my `table` under which `user` comes.

Comment: Clean up formatting and ask an actual question.

Comment: it is like <table class="show_hide" id="show_hide">                 <div class="user">

Comment: sry for this kind of mistakes coz im new to this ..

Comment: currently i am using $.cookie for it and it's not working for postbacks.